# ¿Cómo crear actividad de preferencias, solo una sección en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

En Android Studio cuando se hace uso del generador para crear la actividad de preferencias, crea una usando patrón `vista detalle` en la vista aparece una lista con las secciones y en detalle las preferencias de configuración.

Lo que quiero es eliminar la vista de la lista de secciones porque quiero solo tener una dentro de ella con su sub secciones, como la mayoría de apps.

Pero si se está en una tableta me gustaría que permanezca tal como lo crea en `vista-detalle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solventado parcialmente**
Ya he encontrado la solución, se basa en abrir la actividad `SettingsActivity` especificando que sección se quiere iniciar, indicado el `PreferenceFragment`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra( SettingsActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT,
        SettingsActivity.GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName() );
intent.putExtra( SettingsActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, false );
startActivity(intent);
```

Si en la creación de la actividad de preferencia se le ha indicado su `ParenActivity` es decir la actividad padre de retorno.

si se pulsa la flecha atrás, se situa en listado de secciones, para evitar eso, quitar el ! del  `if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item))` que quede así:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Cómo no tengo disponibilidad de tableta:
No he podido comprobar si se visualiza a la izquierda las secciones.
Acción volver atrás, tampoco lo podido comprobar.